# AngularJS: dynamic compile diretive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Here's the [plunker]:http://plnkr.co/edit/iPsyEAIQWxJIJuneZb8B?p=preview

What I want is when I click login, the auth directive should change template to 'logout.html' automatically , and then when logout clicked, switch to use 'login.html'. 
But so far, I should refresh page manully to make directive to switch template.

How can I achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using routes.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            templateUrl: 'logout.html',
            controller: 'logoutCtrl'
        })
}]);
```

Then you do $location.path('/logout') or $location.path('/login')

Here is the tutorial:
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: For clarity, you should remove `$locationProvider` as a dependency as it is not used in the example you provide.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I know I can change template by this way. But I am considering if I can achieve this just using one directive. Anyway, this is one good way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed a couple of bugs in your plunker. Check it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1X1uMwO4J24zjgeOxBXI?p=preview)

Your major error was the $watch expression. It should be `scope.$watch('authed', function () {});` not `scope.$watch(scope.authed, function () {});`.

I've also played a bit with it and came up with [this version](http://plnkr.co/edit/9NXXbt4V4lwNXpeIjY4M?p=preview). The idea is to separate logon/logout logic with cookie manipulation and get rid of explicit DOM manipulation, $compile() etc.

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve this using just one directive? using two directive will produce two code snippets and one of them isn't needed for each situation. And thank you :)

Comment: thanks. Why you give a version using two directives while my version you fixed can work just one directive. Is it better to use two directives?

Comment: There is no "better" way. You could use [1 directive like that](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nj9wn8NvWOJvcPI7nmSE?p=preview) or even [3 directives](http://plnkr.co/edit/oGEuuUSa9HnLrtoTjfOp?p=preview). It really depends on how complex each piece of functionality is. If something gets too complex you have to start breaking it into smaller pieces (e.g. separate login and logout directives). My objection on your original implentation was the use of jQuery. IMHO, it's something unecessary and more complex than it should.

Comment: Thanks. your answer is great. sorry , no able to up vote for you.